# create-react-app not displayed when deployed on AWS S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

I am having trouble getting my create-react-app to display on browser when deployed via S3 bucket. I have created my build folder with `yarn run build` and uploaded all of the contents of the bulid folder to my S3 bucket. When I go to the URL to view my app I get a blank white screen.

Index.html seems to be deployed and rendering ok, because I put in a test "Hello World" which does render when the URL is visited, however the components of my app are not.

This seems to be a common problem and I have read a few threads on this and tried various suggestions to no avail.

I am aware that some people are having issues with using react-router and solved this issue using HashRouter instead of router. This has not worked for me.

Others suggest changing the package.json "homepage":"." - again this has not resolved my issue.

I have also tried removing the (/) from path to the CSS and scripts in my index.html

Please, any suggestions would be much appreciated

My App.js code is:

```
const App=()=> {


  const[isAuth,setIsAuth] = useState(true)

  return (
    <main>
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
        <Signup/>
        <Login/>
          </Route>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/secure" component={Secure} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/Rounds" component={Rounds} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/Record" component={Record} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/userNumber" component={PatientNumber} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/Id" component={ConfirmId} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/Review" component={ReviewLast} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/Play" component={PlayVid} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/StartRecording" component={StartRecording} isAuthorised={isAuth}/>
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My index.html in the build folder is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="static/css/2.786ae0dd.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="static/css/main.2bb2d7be.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      !(function (e) {
        function r(r) {
          for (
            var n, i, a = r[0], c = r[1], l = r[2], s = 0, p = [];
            s < a.length;
            s++
          )
            (i = a[s]),
              Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, i) &&
                o[i] &&
                p.push(o[i][0]),
              (o[i] = 0);
          for (n in c)
            Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c, n) && (e[n] = c[n]);
          for (f && f(r); p.length; ) p.shift()();
          return u.push.apply(u, l || []), t();
        }
        function t() {
          for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) {
            for (var t = u[r], n = !0, a = 1; a < t.length; a++) {
              var c = t[a];
              0 !== o[c] && (n = !1);
            }
            n && (u.splice(r--, 1), (e = i((i.s = t[0]))));
          }
          return e;
        }
        var n = {},
          o = { 1: 0 },
          u = [];
        function i(r) {
          if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
          var t = (n[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} });
          return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, i), (t.l = !0), t.exports;
        }
        (i.e = function (e) {
          var r = [],
            t = o[e];
          if (0 !== t)
            if (t) r.push(t[2]);
            else {
              var n = new Promise(function (r, n) {
                t = o[e] = [r, n];
              });
              r.push((t[2] = n));
              var u,
                a = document.createElement("script");
              (a.charset = "utf-8"),
                (a.timeout = 120),
                i.nc && a.setAttribute("nonce", i.nc),
                (a.src = (function (e) {
                  return (
                    i.p +
                    "static/js/" +
                    ({}[e] || e) +
                    "." +
                    { 3: "1767dfa7" }[e] +
                    ".chunk.js"
                  );
                })(e));
              var c = new Error();
              u = function (r) {
                (a.onerror = a.onload = null), clearTimeout(l);
                var t = o[e];
                if (0 !== t) {
                  if (t) {
                    var n = r && ("load" === r.type ? "missing" : r.type),
                      u = r && r.target && r.target.src;
                    (c.message =
                      "Loading chunk " +
                      e +
                      " failed.\n(" +
                      n +
                      ": " +
                      u +
                      ")"),
                      (c.name = "ChunkLoadError"),
                      (c.type = n),
                      (c.request = u),
                      t[1](c);
                  }
                  o[e] = void 0;
                }
              };
              var l = setTimeout(function () {
                u({ type: "timeout", target: a });
              }, 12e4);
              (a.onerror = a.onload = u), document.head.appendChild(a);
            }
          return Promise.all(r);
        }),
          (i.m = e),
          (i.c = n),
          (i.d = function (e, r, t) {
            i.o(e, r) ||
              Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t });
          }),
          (i.r = function (e) {
            "undefined" != typeof Symbol &&
              Symbol.toStringTag &&
              Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }),
              Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
          }),
          (i.t = function (e, r) {
            if ((1 & r && (e = i(e)), 8 & r)) return e;
            if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
            var t = Object.create(null);
            if (
              (i.r(t),
              Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }),
              2 & r && "string" != typeof e)
            )
              for (var n in e)
                i.d(
                  t,
                  n,
                  function (r) {
                    return e[r];
                  }.bind(null, n)
                );
            return t;
          }),
          (i.n = function (e) {
            var r =
              e && e.__esModule
                ? function () {
                    return e.default;
                  }
                : function () {
                    return e;
                  };
            return i.d(r, "a", r), r;
          }),
          (i.o = function (e, r) {
            return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r);
          }),
          (i.p = "/"),
          (i.oe = function (e) {
            throw (console.error(e), e);
          });
        var a = (this["webpackJsonprs-login"] =
            this["webpackJsonprs-login"] || []),
          c = a.push.bind(a);
        (a.push = r), (a = a.slice());
        for (var l = 0; l < a.length; l++) r(a[l]);
        var f = c;
        t();
      })([]);
    </script>
    <script src="static/js/2.c46ec8be.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/main.8cf6a815.chunk.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: set both index page and error page to index.html in bucket settings

Comment: @sojin This is the correct answer for me. Thanks